# Как узнать причину взаимоблокировки?

Tags: sql-server

Некоторые запросы отваливаются из-за каких-то взаимоблокировок и я понять не могу их причины.

Можно ли понять, какой запрос мешал тому или иному процессу, что был убит?

> Transaction (Process ID 52) was deadlocked on lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно получить граф взаимоблокировки. XML представление графа содержит тексты запросов и их sql_handle.
Варианты получения:

- ExtendedEvents - существующий system_health или настроить свой сборщик.
- Profiler, события Deadlock graph, дополнительно можно Lock: Deadlock, Lock: Deadlock Chain
- включить флаг DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1), данные по взаимоблокировке попадут в журнал ошибок (пример расположения ‪C:\MSSQL\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG)

Пример обращения к system_health:

```
SELECT XEvent.query('(event/data/value/deadlock)[1]') AS DeadlockGraph 
FROM (
SELECT XEvent.query('.') AS XEvent
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TargetData
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions s ON s.address = st.event_session_address
    WHERE s.NAME = 'system_health'
        AND st.target_name = 'ring_buffer'
    ) AS Data 
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData(XEvent)
) AS source;
```

Пример получения текста запроса по sql_handle:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(0x020000004e1d3121d9d7f150401aa9bf0c26d89db5d5b23c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

Пример создания своего сборщика ExtendedEvents:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Deadlock_Monitor] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlos.scheduler_monitor_deadlock_ring_buffer_recorded,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_deadlock,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_deadlock_chain,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.xml_deadlock_report 
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\Temp\Deadlock_Monitor.xel')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
```